# How do some executables bypass the security prompt?

Tags: windows-10, security

Most of the executables I download open a security prompt, such as:

[image: W10 security prompt]

I've been surprised on more than once occasion, though, that an executable I download for the first time, opens the installer right away, bypassing the security prompt.

**How is this possible?** Did I disable a security check by mistake? Are there some signed executables that Windows considers 100% trusted and do not need to go through the security prompt?

---

**Edit**

I just tried the last 2 software installers that did not give me the prompt on a fresh Windows 10 virtual machine:

- *Everything* from voidtools.com
- *Signal* from signal.org

and same thing, I did not get the prompt.

- For *Everything*, I got a prompt **during installation** asking permission for the app to make changes on the computer.
- For *Signal*, the installation completed with no prompt whatsoever.

So it looks like the prompt appears depending on what the app is trying to access?

**I'm surprised it can execute at all without a prompt, though.**

My guess is that apps in Windows 10 are sandboxed by default, keeping them from tampering with the system. When they can live within the sandbox, no prompt appears. When they require any access outside of the sandbox (e.g. the whole filesystem), windows would prompt the user for authorization.

This could explain why *Signal* (a simple messenger app) does not prompt (it should be able to work sandboxed) while *Everything* does prompt at some point (it needs to access the whole filesystem).

**I'd be happy with some confirmation about this guess**, and some more information if possible.

Comment: Could be that the binary was digitally signed with a previously trusted key

Comment: @ivanivan You mean if I accept once to execute a program signed with a given key, the key would become trusted and further executables signed with the same key would not trigger the prompt? *(Not that I remember installing anything from this developer before, though...)*

Comment: Is it possible that the particular site is in your Trusted Sites list in IE? If so, you won't see the "Always ask before" prompt.

Comment: @w32sh This is, AFAIK the first time I was visiting this site. And I never use IE anyway.

Comment: Please see the update to my question!

Comment: “My guess is that apps in Windows 10 are sandboxed by default, keeping them from tampering with the system.” - Unless you are using the new Windows Sandbox feature this is absolutely not happening.  A previous comment was on the right track.  This prompt only happens on files that have a certain attribute.  An installer doesn’t always need permission elevation.

Comment: @Ramhound There must be something special about these 2 installers, right? I'm probably using the sandbox term wrong, as you're right, sandbox is a special and new feature of Windows 10 as I just discovered. There may still be some kind of *permissions* requested by an executable?

Comment: Unless the installer needs a permission elevation you won’t receive a UAC prompt.  The prompt you are getting only involves if the file in the most simplest terms either a local file or an internet file.  This can be determined by the properties of the file itself.

Comment: Assuming the installer does not require a permission elevation, what happens if it installs a malicious executable? How does Windows protect against this?

Comment: Yes. SmartScreen cloud servers will most likely block the malicious executable using reputation check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft SmartScreen seems to have a given a good reputation for the installers from voidtools.com and signal.org. And I see that these installers are digitally signed.

Quoting from [Microsoft SmartScreen & Extended Validation (EV) Code Signing Certificates – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates/)

> Programs signed by an EV code signing certificate can immediately
>   establish reputation with SmartScreen reputation services even if no
>   prior reputation exists for that file or publisher. Other factors are
>   considered when generating reputation and determining product
>   experiences and EV-signed programs will be closely monitored over
>   time. We think the improvements in the vetting and security of these
>   certificates are a great development for both users and developers.

See also: [code signing - Smart-Screen filter still complains, despite I signed the executable, why? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139347/smart-screen-filter-still-complains-despite-i-signed-the-executable-why/139520#139520)

Quote:

> There are two solutions: either wait till the application has a large
>   user base and its reputation will be adjusted by the Smart Screen.
>   However, the current working status might prevent users from
>   installing and trusting the application. The second option is to sign
>   it with an EV (Extended Validation) code signing certificate.
>   Applications signed with an EV certificate establishes its reputation
>   right away.

After the first run, Windows SmartScreen also removes the Mark-of-the-Web [Zone Identifier](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bulk-unblock-files-downloaded-internet/) from the downloaded files automatically.

Comment: Interesting. So basically, you *can* make Windows trust malicious software by signing it with an EV certificate. But in this case they'll know who to come after. Makes sense I guess.

Comment: Malicious software will be detected.

Microsoft also says `Don’t sign or distribute malicious code: Distributing code detected as malicious will remove the reputation from a file and also any reputation from the associated digital certificate – even if signed with
an EV code signing certificate.`

Moreover, the SmartScreen does only a pre-check. Even if a malicious installer passes the SmartScreen (just in case), your realtime antivirus protection will block it.